# Bootstrap accordion header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have added an + - image to accordion header. When page loads, + sign looks bold. After clicking it looks normal. Is it because of header property> How to fix it ?

```
<accordion-heading is-open="group.open">
                <div class="row" style="height:22px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
                        <label class="aa-blue b h5">{{group.title}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
                        <label class="aa-black b h5">{{group.stn}}</label>
                        <label class="aa-blue b h5">{{group.date}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="h5">{{group.header|cut:true:60:' ...'}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
                            <i ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': isCollapsed, 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': !isCollapsed}"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
</accordion-heading>
```

Comment: put your code into a bootply that shows the problem

Comment: Thanks. I am trying it now. I am using AngularJS. bootply is showing option jQuery only.

Comment: This is pretty weird. I looked at chevron icon example. My code is similar. Why am I getting BOLD icon???